# Performance of a program in C++ that reads non-overlapping segments of a file with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program that processes a huge file (hundreds of GBs) with multiple threads. The program assigns a range of the file to each thread, and then the thread reads that segment from the disk sequentially to do some work. The idea is fully parallelizable as the segments assigned to the threads are non-overlapping.

My problem is that the more threads I use, the poorer the performance of my program is. For instance, in a file of 18GB, if I use one thread, the CPU% my program gets is about 71%. On the other hand, if I use four threads, the CPU% rises to 112% (28% on average for each thread) and runs slightly faster. Considering there is no locking mechanism between, my multi-thread implementation offers litte performance gain.

I understand the problem here is I/O, but I need to understand why it occurs and how to fix it. Each thread has its file descriptor for the file and calls `posix_fadvise` to tell the kernel the corresponding segment is going to be accessed sequentially. Every time the thread asks for a new segment chunk from the disk, it advises the kernel to remove the previous chunk loaded in the thread buffer from the page cache to avoid page-cache trashing (recall that we are dealing with a huge file that is likely to be way bigger than the amount of space available for page caching).

I thought the performance would be better considering the amount of `readhead` for each file descriptor (set via `posix_fadvise` `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED`).

Any help to improve the performance of this code will be appreciated.

This script replicates my procedure:

```cpp
#include "file_iterator.h"
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::string file = std::string(argv[1]); 
    size_t freq[256]={0};
    std::mutex mutex;

    //anonymous function passed to pthreads
    // [start, end) is the file range assigned to the the thread
    auto worker =[&](size_t start, size_t end){

        //the work of every thread in this example consists of counting the symbol frequencies in the range 
        size_t t_freq[256]={0};
        file_iterator<uint8_t> it(file, start, end);
        while(!it.consumed()){
            t_freq[*it]++;
            ++it;
        }

        //store the thread computations in the global variable
        //after the thread finishes its work
        {
            const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            for(size_t i=0;i<256;i++){
                freq[i]+=t_freq[i];
            }

        }
    };

    //argv[2] is the number of threads
    size_t n_threads=size_t(atoi(argv[2]));

    //get input file size
    struct stat st{};
        stat(file.c_str(), &st);
        off_t fsz = st.st_size;

    std::cout<<"File has "<<fsz<<" symbols "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Number of threads: "<<n_threads<<std::endl;

    off_t syms_per_thread = 1 + ((fsz - 1) / n_threads);  //ceil 

    std::cout<<"Syms. per thread "<<syms_per_thread<<std::endl;

    //divide the workload evenly in the threads
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> ranges;
    for(size_t i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
        size_t start = syms_per_thread*i;
        size_t end = std::min<off_t>(fsz, syms_per_thread*(i+1));
        std::cout<<"Thread "<<i<<" : "<<start<<" "<<end<<std::endl; //end is excluding
        ranges.emplace_back(start, end);
    }

    //call and wait for the threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(size_t i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
        threads.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(ranges[i].first), std::ref(ranges[i].second));
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }

    // report the result
    std::cout<<"Symbol frequencies : "<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0;i<256;i++){
        if(freq[i]!=0){
            std::cout<<(uint8_t)i<<" : "<<freq[i]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The content of `file_iterator.h` is a iterator-like class that reads a file segment sequentially in a semi-external way. This is its source code:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename sym_t,
     off_t buff_size=8*1024*1024>
class file_iterator{

    int fd=-1;
    static constexpr uint8_t w_bytes = sizeof(sym_t);
    sym_t *buffer=nullptr;
    std::string file;
    size_t b_pos=0;
    size_t curr_pos;
    size_t last_pos;
    size_t f_offset;

public:
    explicit file_iterator(std::string &_file, off_t start=0, off_t end=0) : file(_file),
                                                                         curr_pos(start){
        struct stat st{};
        stat(file.c_str(), &st);
        off_t fsz = st.st_size;
        off_t tot_syms = fsz / w_bytes;
        assert(tot_syms>0);

        if(start<tot_syms){

            if(end==0) end = tot_syms;
            assert(start<end && end<=tot_syms);

            fd = open(file.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
            assert(fd>0);

#ifdef __linux__
            ssize_t tot_bytes = (end-start)*w_bytes;
            posix_fadvise(fd, start*w_bytes, tot_bytes, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL);
#endif
            buffer = (sym_t *)malloc(buff_size);

            f_offset = start*w_bytes;
            lseek(fd, f_offset, SEEK_SET);
            size_t read_elm = read(fd, buffer, buff_size);
            assert(read_elm>0 && read_elm<=buff_size);
            last_pos = end-1;
        }else{
            curr_pos = tot_syms;
            last_pos = tot_syms;
        }
    }

    inline sym_t operator *() const {
        return buffer[b_pos];
    }

    inline ~file_iterator(){
        free(buffer);
    }

    inline void operator++(){
        b_pos++;
        curr_pos++;
        if(b_pos==buff_size && curr_pos<last_pos){
            ssize_t read_elm = read(fd, buffer, buff_size);
            assert(read_elm>0 && read_elm<=buff_size);
#ifdef __linux__
            posix_fadvise(fd, f_offset, buff_size, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
#endif
            f_offset +=read_elm; 
            b_pos=0;
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool consumed() const {
        return curr_pos>last_pos;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the file on a hard disk or SSD. If its on a hard disk you will likely decrease performance by splitting the I/O into multiple threads.

Comment: It is hard disk. Why is that so?

Comment: On a spinning disk you want to minimize the number of times the read/write head has to move back and forth along the radius of the disk -- everytime it's seeking, it's not reading any data.  If multiple threads are issuing read commands for different locations on the disk, you'll spend a lot of time seeking.   Therefore the optimal pattern for a spinning disk is to read the file straight through in order from beginning to end.

Comment: For a hard disk aim to do large sequential reads or writes for the best performance. This reduces the time spent seeking.

Comment: I see. I suspected the problem was something similar to what @JeremyFriesner mentioned, but I assumed modern hard disk / kernels have smart ways to deal with the situation. Would it be useful to use one thread with a huge buffer, say 1GB? I constantly see on the internet that setting up a big buffer for file streams does not improve performance. I am currently using 8MB.

Comment: If the file consists of a bunch of segments that can be processed individually, then I would suggest a single thread that reads the file into segment-sized buffers. Then have worker threads that are assigned a buffer from the IO thread every time they finish with the last one.

Comment: Why would you expect multiple threads to make this any faster? It won't speed up the disk I/O. And this task is completely dominated by disk I/O time. If 97% of the time is disk I/O and 3% of it is CPU, even making the CPU usage free and perfect would be a 3% speedup, hardly worth the effort.

Comment: @AAA I suggest using a disk-performance utility to measure the raw read-rate of your hard drive -- that will give you a "best case scenario" for your program's performance, in that you know your program will never be able to read in the data off the disk faster than the disk itself can read.  Then you can optimize your program until it shows performance reasonably close to that level; after that, the only thing you can do to get better performance is buy a faster storage device.  I recommend SSDs, they are very fast and have instantaneous seek-time :)

Comment: Even with a SSD you'd find you have a limited number of channels to the disk and the threads would waste time fighting over access to those channels. Too many threads and they'll spend more time fighting than doing useful work. You can also have deviant cases where the disk sees what's coming and loads data into cache for high speed access for one thread, gets interrupted and loads another thread's job into the cache, gets interrupted and loads yet another job into cache... And finally looping back around and redoing a bunch of the work it did earlier because it got squeezed out of the cache.

Comment: You could try to use memory-mapped I/O: map the entire file into memory and then just read from the memory region to access the data of the file. In general memory mapped I/O is going to be faster than using system calls, but if you are indeed already dominated by I/O performance it probably won't have a huge impact.